# Proving that a set is an open set by using the concept of accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need help to prove that, by using the definition of closed sets and accumulation points, the following characterization of open sets holds.

**Definition 1**. An *accumulation point* of $S \subseteq R$ is a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\big\{(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \setminus \{x\}\big\} \cap S \neq \emptyset$.

**Definition 2**. A closed set is a set that contains all its accumulation points.

***To Prove:***
A set $S \subseteq\mathbb{R}$  is open if and only if $\forall x \in S$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subseteq S$.

I have got it going in one direction (I think).

- *Necessary condition*: if $S\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ is open $\implies$   $S^{c}$ is closed $\implies S^{c}$ contains all its accumulation points,
  $\therefore$ $\forall x \in S$, $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $\big\{(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \setminus \{x\}\big\}\cap S^{c} = \emptyset$ ($\because$ no accumulation point of $S^{c}$ can be in $S$)
  $$\implies(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subseteq S
  \quad \forall x \in S
  $$
  and taking $\epsilon = \delta$, we get the desired result.

Would appreciate help on the other direction.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is your definition of closed sets and accumulation points?

Comment: You can't prove a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zwh as noted in his comment, there are some hidden assumptions in your question. Precisely, you define (**Definition 2** above) a closed set as a set which contains all its accumulation points, while in your (completely correct) proof of the sufficient part you use the fact that if $S$ is open then $S^{c}$, which is the (or better one of the) "classical definition"  of a closed set in general topology. This means that *you have to prove that these two properties characterizing closed sets are equivalent*: however, assuming tacitly that you did so before, a proof of the necessary condition goes as follows:

- *Sufficient condition*: if $\forall x \in S$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subseteq S$, and this implies that $\forall x \in S$, it exists $\delta >0$ such that $\big\{(x-\delta, x+\delta) \setminus \{x\}\big\}\cap S^{c} = \emptyset$, since 
  $$
  S\cap S^{c}=\emptyset\iff\text{the ony common subset of $S$ and $S^{c}$ is the empty set}.
  $$
  But this implies that $S$ *does not contain any accumulation point of* $S^{c}$, and since $\mathbb{R}=S\cup S^{c}$ *is a partition of $\Bbb R$ made of two disjoint sets* (i.e. $x\in S$ or $x\in S^{c}$ but not $x\in S\cap S^{c}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$), $S^{c}$ contains all its accumulation points$\implies$ $S^{c}$ is closed and this implies $S$ is open.

**Final note**
The proof works also for general topological spaces $X$. It is sufficient to define accumulation points in terms of the general topological concept of *neighborhood of a point*, and assume the equivalence of properties of closed sets given above (stated in the language of neighborhoods).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense

Comment: You're welcome. I  hope to have been of some help and, if you like the answer, please consider accepting it.